# Invoking super class method without its instance using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

Please consider the below code demonstrating inheritance and reflection :

```
    /*Parent class*/

    package basics;

    public class Vehicle {

        private void parentPrivateMethod() {
            System.out.println("This is the child private method");
        }

        public void print() {
            System.out.println("This is a Vehicle method");
        }

        public void overrideThisMethod() {
            System.out.println("Parent method");
        }

    }


    /*Child class*/

    package basics;

    public class Car extends Vehicle {

        private void childPrivateMethod() {
            System.out.println("This is the child private method");
        }

        public String returnCarName() {
            return "Manza";
        }

        @Override
        public void overrideThisMethod() {
            //super.overrideThisMethod();/*NOTE THIS*/
            System.out.println("Child method");
        }

    }


    /*Tester class*/
    package basics;

    import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
    import java.lang.reflect.Method;

    public class NewTester {

        /**
         * @param args
         * @throws NoSuchMethodException
         * @throws SecurityException
         * @throws InvocationTargetException
         * @throws IllegalAccessException
         * @throws IllegalArgumentException
         * @throws InstantiationException
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) throws SecurityException,
                NoSuchMethodException, IllegalArgumentException,
                IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Car carInstance = new Car();

            /* Normal method invocation */
            carInstance.overrideThisMethod();

            /* Reflection method invocation */
            Method whichMethod = Car.class.getSuperclass().getMethod(
                    "overrideThisMethod", null);
            whichMethod.invoke(carInstance, null);

            /* Work-around to call the superclass method */
            Method superClassMethod = Car.class.getSuperclass().getMethod(
                    "overrideThisMethod", null);
            superClassMethod.invoke(Car.class.getSuperclass().newInstance(), null);
        }

    }
```

The output(with 'NOTE THIS' part commented) is :

```
        Child method
        Child method
        Parent method
```

In case, the 'NOTE THIS' part is un-commented, the superclass method will be invoked, giving an output :

```
        Parent method
        Child method
        Parent method
        Child method
        Parent method
```

When an instance of Car is created, the constructor of Vehicle runs first. Hence, I believe, that an instance of Vehicle is created,too, whose reference the Car instance holds via 'super'.

**Question** :
How can I invoke the superclass version of 'overrideThisMethod' without using the /* Work-around to call the superclass method */ ?

Am I overlooking something here/making wrong assumptions here?

Comment: omg, why in the world would you ever want to the that?

Comment: Bouts of in-sanity :P
I was wondering if super.someOverridenMethod() can be called,why not via reflection ???

Comment: This goes against the whole point of having public, protected, and private modifiers.  Only invoke the methods you have access to.  If you need access to additional methods, then ask the developer to widen the scope for you.  If they won't do it, then build your own class. (Hint:  copy and paste works great)

Comment: You realize that your reflective code is equivalent to `new Vehicle().overrideThisMethod()`, no need for reflection here.

Comment: I agree to every comment above;I believe it can be done by reflection - I just want to know how, though it is a terrible idea for day-to-day usage !

Answer (score 3):

> When an instance of Car is created, the constructor of Vehicle runs first. Hence, I believe, that an instance of Vehicle is created,too, whose reference the Car instance holds via 'super'.

This is not quite correct; only one object is created. The constructor of Vehicle runs because it is an instance of Vehicle as well as of Car. There is no separate Vehicle object, and `super` is not an object reference but a keyword. For example you can't pass `super` to methods as an argument.

The `super` keyword allows you to tell the compiler that you want to call a method from the super class without checking if the method is overridden in subclasses. In order to do this the compiler generates the method call with the `invokespecial` JVM instruction. Normally the compiler would emit an `invokevirtual` instruction.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run the superclass public method, call it from an instance of the superclass.  If you wanted to call the parent method from the child, then it shouldn't have gotten overridden  in the first place.

```
Vehicle v = new Vehicle();
v.overrideThisMethod();
```